# how to set parameters when pipe bash script to bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

How to execute bash script with parameters:

```
./foo.sh a b c
```

When it's compressed (e.g. using `xz`).

```
 xzcat foo.sh | bash <<how_to_supply_here_parameters?>>
```

**Specific usecase:**

I produced very big `rmlint.sh` file and store it compressed:

```
time rmlint -o sh:stdout -c sh:hardlink|tee >( xz > rmlint.sh.xz )
```

Therefore I would normally execute

```
./rmlint.sh -d -x -p
```

However, file is too big to be uncompressed. Therefore I would love to do same by pipe-ing it to bash:

```
xzcat rmlint.sh.xz | bash ...
```

Comment: How big is this script, is it a world record? Did you use functions, or paste/copy code all over the place?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use the `-s` option and `--` to separate arguments you want to pass:

```
echo 'echo "$@"' | sh -s 3 4 5

echo 'printf "{%s}" "$0"; printf " {%s}" "$@"; echo' |
    sh -s -- -d -x -p --foo=bar
{sh} {-d} {-x} {-p} {--foo=bar}
```

This should work with any POSIX shell, not just `bash`. From [susv4](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html):

> `-s`
>       Read commands from the standard input.
>
> If there are no operands and the `-c` option is not specified, the `-s`
>   option shall be assumed.

Comment: There is a problem with this, as my parameters have "-" prefix, therefore I call `bash -s -d -x -p` and get in return : `bash: -d: invalid option` ( https://pastebin.com/JXRiUuLR )

Comment: You use the `--` end of options marker, as usual. See the 2nd example.

Comment: Thank you a lot for help and apologise for stupid overlook! You helped me to find what I was overlooking (to short sleep Today), which was `--` - Thank you! Now it works perfectly!

Comment: Added `--` to first line of your solution as it was something I overlooked, so I hope it will help some others, who may overlook it as well